# How to change default dropdown from php to jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropdown

I have some code for dropdown default, data structure, and my view page. i dont have any problem from my code using php. but i want to change thats code from php to jquery.

- This is my default dropdown php code:

```php
<select class="form-control pilihData" id="pilihModel" name="pilihModel">
    <?php
    global $pilih;
    error_reporting(0);
    if (isset($_POST['cari'])) :
        if ($_POST['pilihData'] == 'Abdullah') :
            foreach ($pilih as $plh) : ?>
                <option <?php if ($plh['model'] == 'hummer 3') : echo "selected";
                endif; ?> value="<?= $plh['model']; ?>"><?= $plh['model']; ?></option>
            <?php
            endforeach;
        elseif ($_POST['pilihData'] == 'Hasan') :
            foreach ($pilih as $plh) : ?>
                <option <?php if ($plh['model'] == 'toyota avanza') : echo "selected";
                endif; ?> value="<?= $plh['model']; ?>"><?= $plh['model']; ?></option>
            <?php
            endforeach;
        elseif ($_POST['pilihData'] == 'Ahmad') :
            foreach ($pilih as $plh) : ?>
                <option <?php if ($plh['model'] == 'honda brio') : echo "selected";
                endif; ?> value="<?= $plh['model']; ?>"><?= $plh['model']; ?></option>
            <?php
            endforeach;
        endif;
    endif;
    ?>
</select>
```

- this is my view page, and data structure :
  [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there a special reason why you want to do that, or a special jQuery functionality you want to use ?

Comment: the reason is :
to much line code for 3 user hasan, ahmad, abdullah. so, its impossible if i have thousand user or more for using this code

Comment: But the only reason you have 5 lines of code for each person is because you hardcode the condition for the selected option in your script. That would not change using jquery

Comment: you have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "change from php to jquery"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the script checks for each person which option should be preselected. That leads to a lot of unwanted code repitition. JQuery won't solve that problem.

A much better way would be to keep track of the selected option/s in the database. So you don't have 1 but at least 2 relations between your classes `user` and `mobil`. The first being which options of `mobil` are selectable for which `user`, and the second being which `user` has selected which option of `mobil`.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) are the wiki articles about relations between classes.

If you want a user to have exactly 1 option selected you could save the corrosponding `id_mobil` in the `user` entitiy by introducing a new field in the `user` class.

If a `user` gets selected in your first dropdown you need to get the selectable options as well as the new field which option is selected. and then the code to create the new select field would be the same for each `user`. Somthing like this :

```
<?php
foreach ($pilih as $plh) : ?>
  <option <?php if ($plh['id_model'] == $selectedUser['id_model']) : echo "selected"; endif; ?>value="<?= $plh['model']; ?>"><?= $plh['model']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```